# pg_basebackup in postgres is giving error as I have created tablespace inside $pg_data directory

Tags: postgresql-13

/usr/pgsql-13/bin/pg_basebackup -h hostname -p 5432 -D /home/pgsql/13/data29/ -X stream --progress -U postgres -R
pg_basebackup: error: could not create directory "/home/pgsql/13/data29/test_tablespace": File exists
pg_basebackup: removing data directory "/home/pgsql/13/data29"

test_tablespace is folder created inside $pg_Data directory to store tablespace.

But now I am not able to start straming replication as pg_basebackup is giving error.

I am trying to get basebackup for starting straming replication